# stringbyreplacingoccurrencesofstring not working for \ in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I'm trying to replace the " ' " with " \' " in my code while preparing a json string to pass it to the .NET server but it is not working ...
My input is  "As'@k" and i need to get "As\'@k" as out put..my code is below

```
NSString *myString=@"As'@k";
NSString *tempString=@"\'";
myString=[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:tempString];
NSLog(@"MYSTRING: %@",myString);
```

is not getting the output as "As\'@k" . Why?

Help Me..

Comment: `NSString *tempString=@"\\'";`

Comment: Why don't you use NSJSONSerialization instead of "manually" creating the JSON? That would handle all the escaping and quoting stuff automatically.

Comment: @MartinR Ugh, I never read the JSON part. You should write your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   NSString *myString=@"As'@k";
   myString=[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\\'"];
   NSLog(@"MYSTRING: %@",myString);
```

Answer (score 4):

Since `\` is a special character used for escaping, you need to use `\\` if you want the backslash character:

```
NSString *tempString=@"\\'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use @"\\" as \ is an escape character so you need to escape it otherwise it is ignored

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
NSString *myString=@"As'@k";
NSString *tempString=@"\\'";   //because it is escape sequence character
myString=[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:tempString];
NSLog(@"MYSTRING: %@",myString);
```

Answer (score -2):

Include regexkit lite in your project from [here](https://github.com/samdeane/RegexKitLite)

include header file in your project

```
#import "RegexKitLite.h"
```

add the following method in your code.

```
-(NSString*)backSlashCorrectionForString:(NSString*)originalString
{
   NSError *error = nil;
    NSRegularExpression *regex =
        [NSRegularExpression 
  regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\s" 
                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
    NSString *newString =
        [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:originalString
        options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [originalString length]) withTemplate:@"\\s"];

    //NSLog(@"New string: %@",newString);
    return newString;
}
```

Comment: @manujmv: Your code sample replaces white space by `%20`. That is completely different from what has been asked.